# Dynamic body background color in svelte

Tags: css, tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit

I am not sure what i am asking for but here is the problem:

[image]

the background color of the page is a certain color but the background color of the page is another (if I understand what's going on correctly). You can see that when I for example swipe up to reload or get to the bottom of the page. also in this screenshot, I am using Safari which uses translucid "color" in the UI so the background background color being white effects that.

My solution?
I simply changed the body color in my core.css file which is used on my layout. worked perfectly as it should.

But then I want to use a white background color on another page, but then the background background color is the dark-blue color.

My idea is to dynamically change the body background color dynamically (perhaps using stores) but if there is another solution, hit me.

I am using tailwind for all CSS but the solution does not require tailwind.